# Assigning multiple global variables in JavaScript with one function

Tags: javascript

I've been looking around for a while and cant seem to find a solution to this question.

I have three global variables declared in JavaScript, which haven't been assigned yet such as:

```
var GLOBAL_VARIABLE_ONE;
var GLOBAL_VARIALLE_TWO;
var GLOBAL_VARIABLE_THREE;
```

Lets say I have a function which I pass a two parameters, one of them is a url string to make an ajax call to retrieve a JSON object, the other is the global variable which I want to assign the returned JSON to. Thus, I have a function as such:

```
function getBackList(urlName, globalVariable) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: urlName,
    }).done(function (returned_data) {
        globalVariable = $.parseJSON(returned_data);
    });
}
```

I want to be able to call the function like:

```
getBackList("\some\url", GLOBAL_VARIABLE_ONE);
```

and assign the object to the global.

Now, I realize that using global variables are not recommended and I understand that due to variable hoisting, the arguments passed to a function are locally scoped. However, I need to be able to access these global variables in other functions after they have been assigned.

My question is how can I pass the global variables and assign them into the one function above, without having to create separate functions to assign each one explicitly (which works by the way but creates a lot of code redundancy)?

Comment: Check this question just in case, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Globals are great, and using one function you can call many times to set a lot of global variables is considered good practice.

Comment: Global variables should not be used too much. It is considered anti-pattern. Global variables create state witch make software very tight coupled and hard to debug.

Comment: @user1759572 - nonsense, global variables are the best thing to happen to javascript ever, it's like sand in sahara, it should be everywhere.

Comment: happy writing enterprise/concurrent software with a lot of global variables. JavaScript by nature is callback/event based language.

Comment: @adeneo I'm not sure if you're being serious or sarcastic. I'm am very new to JS and a lot of these concepts are new to me.

Comment: @user1759572 Yeah from what I've been reading it is bad practice to use too many global, I'm looking at different ways to approach the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

global variables are actually members of the `window` object. So you could do:

```
function getBackList(x, variableName) {
  // .. stuff ..
  window[variableName] = $.parseJSON(returned_data);
}

getBackList(x, 'GLOBAL_VARIABLE_ONE');
```

Comment: 16 seconds too slow :-P

Comment: @dandavis yeah but I have included the getBackList call. Just kidding.

Comment: tisk tisk, but by our powers combined...  ;)

Comment: Thanks Ill accept this answer since it was first, but voted both up.

Comment: @dnak mine was first :-P But who is counting? Good job jods ^_^

Answer (score 4):

```
function getBackList(urlName, globalVariableName) {
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: urlName,
    }).done(function (returned_data) {
        window[globalVariableName] = $.parseJSON(returned_data);
    });
}
```

Pass in the global variable's name instead ^^^

Answer (score 3):

Javascript won't allow that as it's passing the variable.

If `GLOBAL_VARIABLE_ONE` is an object it'll pass a reference.

Examples:

```
a = {}
```

`a` now references the new object.

```
b = a;
```

`b` now references the same object that a references. Note that it does not reference `a`.

With `a = {}; b = a`, you get

```
a
 \
  \
   { }
  /
 /
b
```

Then with `a['one'] = {}` you get

```
a
 \
  \
   { one: { } }
  /
 /
b
```

In order to achieve what you want you'll want `GLOBAL_VARIABLE_ONE` to be an object.

So you can do:

```
var GLOBAL_OBJECT = {};
getBackList("\some\url", GLOBAL_OBJECT['GLOBAL_VARIABLE_ONE']);
```

Or you can do:

```
var GLOBAL_VARIABLE_ONE = {}
var GLOBAL_VARIALLE_TWO = {}
var GLOBAL_VARIABLE_THREE = {}

function getBackList(urlName, globalVariable) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: urlName,
    }).done(function (returned_data) {
        globalVariable.json = $.parseJSON(returned_data);
    });
}

getBackList("\some\url", GLOBAL_VARIABLE_ONE);
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually like this answer alot.

Comment: This is cleaner than passing strings for variable names